# How to call specific stage\job from downstream pipeline in gitlab

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

downstream pipeline

```
stages:
  - build
  - deploy

build_project:
  stage: build
  script:
    - cd ./some-dir
    - build-script.sh

deploy_project:
  stage: deploy
  Trigger:
    - cd ./some-dir
    - deploy-script.sh
```

How to call only "stage: deploy"  ?

```
microservice_a:
  trigger:
    include:
      - project: 'my-group/my-pipeline-library'
        ref: 'main'
        file: '/path/to/child-pipeline.yml'
```

In Gitlab is it possible to call specific stage from child pipeline ?